# Getting ip address and putting it to socket -java

Tags: java, sockets, nullpointerexception, network-programming, ip-address

```
InetAddress ipAddr;
```

What i'm trying to do here is i need to get ip address and then put it in socket

```
 public class L implements ActionListener{
  public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e){
      try {   
            s = new Socket(ipAddr.getHostAddress(), 6111);

            DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            dout.writeUTF("L");
            dout.writeUTF(" ");
      } catch (IOException ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();  
      }

  }
}
```

I'm having this error msg

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting this error because you're trying to call method on a null reference. You need to initialise `ipAddr` before using it to call methods which is described later in this answer.

```
s = new Socket(ipAddr.getHostAddress(), 6111);   // your code doesn't initialise ipAddr.
```

Currently, it is unclear from your question which IPAddress you want. So, I'm assuming you're looking for your system's loopback address (default). There are several options to initialise InetAddress as shown below:

```
    String url = "localhost";
    byte addr[] = {127, 0, 0, 1};  // loopback address
    InetAddress ip1 =  InetAddress.getByName(url);
    InetAddress ip2 =  InetAddress.getByAddress(addr);
    InetAddress ip3 =  InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    // proceed with your sample code by using any of these InetAddress references
```